# Geodata to make a map of the UK with counties outlined

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I will be using AngularJS and D3.js, but that's not really important.

[This blog post](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) by the developer of D3.js, which is a fantastic JavaScript charting library, shows how he made a map of the UK from open source data and delimited each of the countries, giving each of them a different colour.

He also labelled major cities, which, for me, is very "nice  to have", but not complete "must have".

I would like to take that one step of granularity further, by delineating the individual counties, as well as countries.

Does anyone know of any open data which already does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I went with http://d-maps.com/ I don't think there is anything to beat it!

Comment: what about d-maps did you go with? where is the data that you used?

Comment: A fair question, I guess (+1). I hadn't wanted to state, becuase they simply have so much that everyone should look for themself. Of the 92 (!) gratis UK maps,I chose http://d-maps.com/m/europa/uk/royaumeuni/royaumeuni86.svg   I have been looking on & off for a few years & have not found any other site which comes close to this

Answer (score 4):

The Ordnance Survey have a wealth of Open Source data that can be used free of charge. The data set you want for counties is [Boundary-Line](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html). The data is supplied as shape or mapinfo, but the blog post you referred to covers the process of converting the shape files to JSON.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty ignorant about the details of UK geography, but I found this dataset of only [English ceremonial counties](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/ceremonial-county-boundaries-of-england).

The Ordinance Survey website has [this interactive map of counties past and present](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/counties/index.html), going beyond England.

However, county data isn't clearly listed in their ["Open Data Products"](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/opendata-products.html) so perhaps it's only available under their other licensing terms? Asking them directly might pay off.