# UK cities longitude and latitude details

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I require a list of data on UK cities giving longitude and latitude details. Preferably in CSV or Excel format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geodata to make a map of the UK with counties outlined](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6641/geodata-to-make-a-map-of-the-uk-with-counties-outlined)

Comment: I'm not so sure that is a duplicate, because it asks for county boundaries. The OP may need central coordinates. @NWTH please [edit] your question to tell us *exactly* what you need.

Comment: I reverted the last few edits - the question was changed to asking for cinema locations, thereby invalidating all answers.

Comment: As the OP of the "possible duplicate" I can assure you that this is not a duplicate. The OP here is not asking for "outline", just one lat/long per city

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use OpenStreetMap (OSM) for this. OSM is a open database of geographical features. OSM features are described by *tags*, that are combination of *key*-*value* pairs.

The entry point to look at the geographical features of OSM is this page: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features, which describes the major features that are mapped in OSM. Look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features#Places for the section about places. "Cities" in OSM are be described by `place=city`. If you need more little towns, you can search for `place=town`, `place=village`, etc. (see the above link for more tags of places in OSM).

To query the data in OSM, you can use http://overpass-turbo.eu/. Use the wizard (one of the top tab), type "city in UK", increase the timeout up to 60s and run the query. Or just click on this share link since I just tried it ;-) : http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/orK. 
You can then export the result in geojson and convert it to a csv with the city name, latitude, longitude. There is also additional information that you may discard.

I'm not aware of open UK gov data, but it might be an other possible source.

J.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best source of GB data is the Ordnance Survey - in this case you want the [Open-Names](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-names.html) product.

Answer (score 4):

Areas/ boundaries of UK cities and major towns from the *Open Geography Portal* at the UK Office for National Statistics:

[Major Towns and Cities (December 2015) Boundaries](http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/58b0dfa605d5459b80bf08082999b27c_0?geometry=-6.172%2C52.56%2C2.172%2C53.55)

Available as .csv/.kml/.shp

Comment: The OP here is not asking for "boundaries ", just one lat/long per city

Comment: 1. The OP is vague and requests "giving longitude and latitude details". That doesn't explicitly say boundaries or one lat/long.

Comment: 2. From the boundaries you can extract one lat/long, either a centroid or a randomly generated point.

Answer (score 4):

Go to [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/):

> The GeoNames geographical database covers all countries and contains over eleven million placenames that are available for download free of charge.

[Here is the data info](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt) for the files that you can download [here](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/), you need the file with the [two-character ISO country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) `GB.ZIP`, currently containing 61069 entries in CSV format.

They have all kinds of support as well.