# UK Cities and Towns

Tags: data-request, uk, city, population

I've scoured the internet (including stack exchange) and trialled a few datasets but none have suited my needs. I'm after UK town and city names with long/lat positions and **populations** (so I can style which towns to label by rules).

I'm aware of the OS Names product but that doesn't have populations and there are hundreds of spreadsheets to amalgamate into a single usable .csv file.

I found this (global dataset): https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database which is ideal. However the file is too big to clip and QGIS's clipping window closes as soon as I run it.

Comment: I require populations as well

Comment: The GeoNames DB that I referenced [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11037/4293) has population data, but the number of records containing actual population data <> 0 is low (maybe 20%)

Comment: The maxmind page you link itself says its obsolete, but one option would be to download and clip using a separate standalone program (eg, Perl script) and then import into qgis?

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/uk-cities-longitude-and-latitude-details).

OpenStreetMap has a tag "[population](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:population)" as well. I've checked about half of the cities in the query [here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/orK) and there was always a population tag with some value. However, there is no source:population tag so we don't know the source and the up-to-dateness of this data.

Answer (score 1):

I would source the population statistics and the Lat/Lon information separately and just perform a simple join to amalgamate the datasets. Census population info can be downloaded [here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/2011censuskeystatisticsandquickstatisticsforwardsandoutputareasinenglandandwales/r22ewrttableqs102ewladv1_tcm77-296538.xls), with further options on  -

https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/2011censuskeystatisticsandquickstatisticsforwardsandoutputareasinenglandandwales

Once the necessary datasets have been sourced a join with a product such as OS Open Names can provide the required output.